# Interaction with updated/entered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, enter

I wonder how to solve this problem in D3.js. This code below enters, updates or exits every 5 seconds and show up or disappear a random number of `name` elements that are part in the array `dataset`. This array also contains `id` elements. Now i want to click on a updated element that appears on screen, for example `"foo"` and want it's `id` (that means 1) shows up after I clicked that `"foo"`element. The name of the function is called `testfunction`, but i think something is not right with that function. The problem is, that the original `name` texts all disappear after click on it and the new `id` text appear. But i want them to be both on screen after using the `click`function Hope some of you guys can help. Thanks

```
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

  var dataset = [{
  name: "foo", id: "1" 
}, {
  name: "bar",  id: "2"
}, {
  name: "baz", id: "3"
}, ];

        print(dataset);

        setInterval(() => {
          var data = dataset.slice(Math.random() * 6);
          print(data);
        }, 7000);

        function print(data) {

            var texts = svg.selectAll(".texts")
                .data(data);

            textsExit = texts.exit().remove();

            textsEnter = texts.enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "texts");

            textsUpdate = texts.merge(textsEnter)
                .attr("x", 10)
                .attr("y", (d, i) => 20 + i * 16)
                .text((d,i) => "TextNumber" + (i+1) + ", name: " + d.name)
                .on("click", testfunction);

    function testfunction(){

                    textsUpdate
                    .attr("x", 200)
                    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return (490 + i * 28)})
                    .text(function(d, i) { return "IDNumber" + (i+1) + ", Name: "+ d.id})



                    };


        }
```

Comment: Just eyeballing it, I would suspect that line should be `.on("click", testfunction);` but I  make no guarantees

Comment: You are def. right on that. I just edited the code and description a bit, because there is still a problem. Thanks so much, Lucas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, the issue here is that you're changing your `textsUpdate` attributes, which will of course change `textsUpdate`'s text positions (they don't *disappear*, though).

A solution is creating *another* text element:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var dataset = [{
  name: "foo",
  id: "1"
}, {
  name: "bar",
  id: "2"
}, {
  name: "baz",
  id: "3"
}, ];

var testText = svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 100);

print(dataset);

setInterval(() => {
  var data = dataset.slice(Math.random() * 6);
  print(data);
}, 7000);

function print(data) {

   testText.text("");

  var texts = svg.selectAll(".texts")
    .data(data);

  textsExit = texts.exit().remove();

  textsEnter = texts.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "texts");

  textsUpdate = texts.merge(textsEnter)
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", (d, i) => 20 + i * 16)
    .attr("cursor", "pointer")
    .text((d, i) => "TextNumber" + (i + 1) + ", name: " + d.name)
    .on("click", function(d, i) {
      testfunction(d, i);
    });

  function testfunction(data, index) {

    testText.text(function() {
        return "IDNumber" + (index + 1) + ", Name: " + data.id
      })

  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. This is nice, but my goal was, that the new text updates everytime, too. That means when i click `"foo"` then only `"1"` should appear. When  i click `"bar"`. then only `"2"` should appear and `"1"` should disappear. That is the reason why i tried to use `textsUpdate` in `testfunction`.

Comment: Check the new snippet. Is this what you want?

Comment: You are a big help as always! Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe explain what you are doing with `testText.text("");` ? Why you are creating an empty text element with that line?

Comment: Just to erase the previous text.